# Is it possible to access a MS Access database with PHP on a Linux Web Server?

Tags: php, ms-access, ubuntu

Ideally it would be brilliant if I could upload an .mdb file to a linux webserver and query it using php. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have ODBC drivers for Unix installed, or a better way would probably be to use PDO with php5.

*Stolen from elsewhere on the net, not tested.

```
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\accounts.mdb;Uid=Admin");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like it is possible using [mdbtools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) ([in the repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mdbtools)), which should allow odbc access as well as a way to port to a different database.

Even if you can't use it directly, [porting is an option](http://mediakey.dk/~cc/mdb-tools-to-export-migrate-from-mdb-microsoft-access-format-to-mysql/).

Comment: The "porting is an option" link is dead. Do you have another one for that tool or another tool that works with MS-Access 2013 or newer?

Answer (score -1):

This question and answer may be of interest: [PHP and Microsoft Access database - Connection and CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605473/how-to-operate-access-with-php)