# ms-access database to mysql database by php

Tags: php

How we can convert a ms-access database to mysql database by php…
or
How we can access a ms-access database by php..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605473/php-and-microsoft-access-database-connection-and-crud/1605554#1605554

Answer (score 0):

For accessing a MS Access database on Windows through ODBC, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_db_odbc.asp).

Answer (score 0):

> How we can convert a ms-access
>   database to mysql database by php

You can export via an ODBC connector or (if you don't have too many tables) you can export your data to a text file and then import it into MySQL (after creating the tables manually) via [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/LOAD_DATA.html). Right-click on the tables and choose `Export` for available options.

For more detailed info on migrating from MS Access to MySQL, check out this great article from the MySQL Dev Team:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/LOAD_DATA.html

> How we can access a ms-access database
>   by php

You can do this easily right through PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code to connect to Access database. I tried this code in PHP,working on Windows XP with XAMPP's Apache server, and using Access 2007 file as a database. Just create your access file and try this :

1. First go to Start menu > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources(ODBC) > System DSN > Add.. > Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb) and show your access file. Give name to the connection.
2. Then write in your *.php file this code:

`

```
<?php
$host= "host_name";
$user= "user_name";
$pass= "password";
$db_connect=odbc_connect($host,$user,$pass); //connect to access file as database

if (!$db) //In case if you didn't connect , you'll get this error message
{
  echo "Can't connect";
  exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";   //pulling data form Access file
$row = odbc_exec($db, $query);
while(odbc_fetch_row($row)
{
   $row1 = odbc_result($row,1);
   $row2 = odbc_result($row,2);
   $row3 = odbc_result($row,3); 
   echo $row1." ".$row2." ".$row3."<br>"; //watching if data is taken correctly
}
?>
```

And then you can insert that rows into sql database by adding this code into the while loop :

```
<?php
  $db="MySQLdatabaseName";
  $db_connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  mysql_select_db($db, $db_connect);
  $insert_into_MySQL = "INSERT INTO table_name($row1,$row2,$row3) 
          VALUES('".$row1."', '".$row2."', '".$row3."'); ";\\These are 2 lines to be 
  mysql_query($insert_into_MySQL );                          \\added to the while loop
?>
```