# Simple Access to PHP

Tags: php, ms-access-2007

How can I read an data from [access database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/) (*.mdb) and get the column data types? More specifically, insert the data from [Access](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) into a MySQL database?

This is what I'm aiming for...

1. Connect to Access (*.mdb) with authentication.
2. Get data types of Access.
3. Create corresponding data types in MySQL.
4. Insert data.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling it yet?  I did, found most of what you were looking for.

Comment: I did find how to connect, but I'm looking to migrate access database structure to mysql too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP and Microsoft Access database - Connection and CRUD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605473/php-and-microsoft-access-database-connection-and-crud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To migrate from one base to another database, the first thing is to have the same table structure.

Then, to read from a database of ACCESS can do something like ( http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-exec.php#71615 ):

```
$emp_id = $_GET['emp_id'];
$stmt = odbc_prepare($db_conn, "SELECT pwd FROM employees WHERE emp_id=?");
$res = odbc_execute($stmt, array($emp_id));
```

Then, with the results, you must perform the commands of inspection at the MySQL database ( http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php). For example.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Export your database on MS Access using ODBC format.

If you are using Xampp
Click Start | Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Data Sources (ODBC) and open the ODBC Data Source Administrator window as shown.

If not install MySQL Connector/ODBC driver

Access can make ODBC connections to MySQL servers over the network. You can still use the contents of your tables through Access, but the tables themselves are hosted by the MySQL server.

I just briefed the process
You might find many other ways or how to use ODBC on googling.

Thank you.