# connect php with access database without using odbc bridge

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

iam working on a project i need to connect php with the access database in the clients computer Is there any way i do this with out using ODBC and creating data source?

for example: in JRE8.x.x we can connect java with access database without ODBC by using UcanAccess. but what for PHP?

Comment: You can use [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605473/php-and-microsoft-access-database-connection-and-crud)

Comment: also in Pdo i have to use ODBC....
can you give me a code dont use ODBC

Comment: You could use [ODBTP](http://odbtp.sourceforge.net). That would avoid ODBC on your machine (the one running PHP), but it would require ODBC on the machine with the Access database on it. Or, you could use [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) in PHP with an OleDB provider.

Comment: Why not switch off of Access to a real database system like mysql already?

Comment: I should point out that in an intranet environment you could have a mysql or mssql server house the data, and then make MS Access files that can access (both read and write) the data via link tables. (But those Access files would use ODBC to connect to the server obviously)