# php - access database connection - Fatal error

Tags: php, database, ms-access

I've been trying to connect to access using php, but a connection error keep appearing. 
The code is:

```
<?php

function ConnectToDatabase()
{
    $connectionstring = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Assignment5\\Data\\assignment5.mdb';
    $dbHandle =new PDO($connectionstring);
    $dbHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbHandle;
}

?>
```

The error is:

**Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment5\connection.php on line 6**

I have already enabled the extension in php.ini, but it still does not work.

Comment: What's the rest of the error?

Comment: @aynber You have to guess it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP and Microsoft Access database - Connection and CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605473/php-and-microsoft-access-database-connection-and-crud)